# Optimizing image loading in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, picasso

We can set the src of an ImageView in xml :

```
android:src="@drawable/image"
```

We can also set the background in xml :

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

If I replace these with programmatically setting the image using Picasso will it reduce the memory consumption by hopefully caching/recycling the bitmaps, resizing, using .fit() ?

Comment: Hi, Have you done this idea? Was memory good when using Picasso, or Glide to loading resource by programmatically?

Comment: Using Picasso for resources produces a noticeable lag. I'd suggest not use it for small images.

Comment: It means those libs just only use for loading network images. No optimization difference if using them for loading drawable resources ?

Comment: If a tiny lag does not kill your UX go ahead and use Picasso for resources as well. In my opinion don't use it for images like tick marks, plus sign, etc. I hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: As I understand, use them for large drawable, with the tiny we skip using them. Anyway, thank for your responding !

Answer (score 0):

You cant load bitmap or drawable from Picasso/Glide/UniversalImageLoader library ...

Check for displaying Bitmaps optimizing:

> http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: What ? I am already doing this picasso.load(R.drawable.phone).into(networkStatus)

Comment: Ok, sorry, if you edit in memory your Image, you cant use the library, but if you have some file in you drawable folder, you will reduce the memory conumption and dont get a OutOfMemoryException...